# How to clear custom smiley from UITextView

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I have a UITextView with combination of text and custom smileys (Attached using NSTextAttachment). And I have a custom UIButton action in which I need to clear the single character from textview’s text. My questions are below.

1. How to find out whether it is text or NSTextAttachment at cursor location in UITextView.
2. After finding, how to clear that single character or NSTextAttachment from that string.

I tried a lot, but couldn’t get it. Any ideas please..

Thanks

Comment: did you use isKindOfClass method? This will tell you if it is a NSTextAttachment or a NSString object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can find the class of the object by using `isKindOfClass` method. This will tell you whether the object is of class `NSTextAttachment` or `NSString`.
2. I am assuming you are using `NSMutableAttributedString`, if so then just find out the range of the character and delete it using `deleteCharactersInRange:` method of `NSMutableAttributedString`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
-(IBAction)yourButton:(id)sender {
       yourUITextView.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@" Your text here, omit the smiley."];
}
```

Comment: The textview's text comes under NSMutableAttributedString or NSAttributedString since it contains both text and NSAttachments. We can't use NSString here.